# How to search through a plist repeatedly?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to learn LISP and I'm getting hung up on something basic -

I want to loop through a list and lookup a plist value from the list value...

```
; here it just looks up the plist value 
(defun get-plist-value(x) (getf (list :a "1" :b "2") x))


; this is what i want to do, but it doesnt work 
; i have tried concatenating the ":" before the x value, but it didnt work either 
(loop for x in '(a b) do (get-plist-value x))

; this works 
(get-plist-value :a)
```

thank you :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `(loop for x in '(a b) do (get-plist-value x))`

There are two issues here.

First, the symbol `a` is not the same as the symbol `:a` (unless you're in the `keyword` package, which is very unlikely), so it will fail to find anything.  Likewise for `b`.

Second, this will look up a value, return it from the `get-plist-value` call, *and then discard it* without doing anything with it.  If you want to collect all found items into a new list and have the loop return that list, use `collect` rather than `do`; if you want to output the found items, use something like `do (format t "~&~A" (get-plist-value x))`; and so on.

**Addendum:** Note that the colon in the printed representation of `:a` is an artifact of how symbols are printed.  The colon is a *package prefix* which signifies that the symbol is in the `keyword` package.  It's *not* a part of the symbol's name, so simply concatenating symbol names isn't going to help.  If you want `get-plist-value` to compare symbols by name only, you can do something like the following, although it's probably not the prettiest possible solution:

```
(defun get-plist-value (x)
  (getf (list :a "1" :b "2")
        (intern (symbol-name x) "KEYWORD")))
```

Comment: I tried using format t but i was mssing the ~&.  Thank you for the detailed solution - makes sense :-)

Answer (score 4):

Just list the keywords:

```
(loop for x in (list :a :b)
      collect (get-plist-value x))
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer works as well - i credited matthias since he answered first :-) but i'll upvote ya